# Is there a Python API for drawing diagrams (that use lines to connect corresponding values between two lists)

Tags: python, api, graphics, diff

Given two lists, which contain same elements of string but in different orders, is there any API that can draw diagrams like
[image]

The diagram consists of two stacks of string. Between these two stacks, lines are used to link same elements between these two stacks.

Its outlook is similar as the visualization of sonar (an Eclipse code diff. tool), but the semantics of lines are different.

Does this kind of diagram have some formal name?

Comment: As the answers to your questions did not include any information about how to name such diagrams I opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016050/diagram-of-two-lists-that-connects-elements-nm Maybe you can answer it by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general graph description format [DOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) seems the most appropriate to me: it is easy to describe a huge variety of graphs, with this (text) format, and you can plot them with one of the many tools available ([Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) comes to mind, for example).

You also have the specialized [python-graph](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/) module at your disposal (which can work with the DOT format too).

Comment: Thanks, I almost forget the DOT family APIs. I decide to realize it with networkx (http://networkx.lanl.gov/).

Comment: @吳強福: I had forgotten about networkx.  Looks like a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

With python you have many options, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326300/python-best-library-for-drawing) for more. I would recommend [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), 
take a look at this [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/line_with_text.html).

Comment: While matplotlib can certainly plot many things, it is does not provide much help with graphs like those referred to in the question.  They are certainly doable with matplotlib, but it's not a tool designed for them.