# Diagram of two lists that connects elements n:m

Tags: gridview, gwt, diagram, gxt

There has been a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528224/is-there-a-python-api-for-drawing-diagrams-that-use-lines-to-connect-correspond) to a specific kind of grid:

[image]

The question has already been answered but the questioner also asked if this kind of diagram has a formal name which is what I'm interested in and the accepted answer doesn't include such information.

Is there any simple way to achieve something like this in GWT/GXT (apart from drawing the two lists and these lines manually)?